# How to set the `DateTimeInterface` default value

Tags: php, symfony

I have this `DateTimeInterface` and I want to set the default value in `Symfony6`

```
#[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
private ?\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt = new \DateTimeMutable('now');
```

However this says `New expressions are not supported in this context`

How can set the default value for this?

Comment: Why not use the object's constructor for this?

Comment: If you are using php8.1 you can use similar syntax thanks to the [new initializers](https://www.php.net/releases/8.1/en.php#new_in_initializers) and constructor promotion: `class Example { public function __construct(private \DateTimeInterface = new DateTimeImmutable()) {} }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default value in constructor

```
public function __construct(\DateTimeInterface date = new DateTime("now")) {
  $this->updatedAt = date;
}
```

Have a great day !

Comment: Thank you default constructor works fir this purpose!